# D3-Chord: Flowing circle elements on chord-path mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I am trying to implement an animation effect using svg circle elements on the mouse-over event of a chord path in D3 chord diagram.
The inspiration for this trial is the following implementation of a sankey diagram:
https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/ed0ae1c70256849dab3e35a0241389c9

I have managed to insert the circle elements on the mouse-over event for the chords. However, I am having difficulty in figuring out how to make them follow the path of the chord. (Line 69-106 in the following JS code).

My JS code (chord.js)

```
//*******************************************************************  
//  CREATE MATRIX AND MAP  
//*******************************************************************  

var matrix, mmap, rdr;  
d3.csv('data/out.csv', function(error, data) {  
   var mpr = chordMpr(data);  

   mpr.addValuesToMap('Source')  
     .setFilter(function(row, a, b) {  
       return (row.Source === a.name && row.Destination === b.name)  
     })  
     .setAccessor(function(recs, a, b) {
       if (!recs[0]) return 0;
       return +recs[0].Count;
     });

   matrix = mpr.getMatrix();
   mmap = mpr.getMap();
   rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);
   drawChords();  
});

//*******************************************************************
//  DRAW THE CHORD DIAGRAM
//*******************************************************************
function drawChords() {
var w = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
h = 700,
r1 = h / 2,
r0 = r1 - 150;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", "circle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

var chord = d3.layout.chord()
    .padding(.15)
    .sortChords(d3.descending);

chord.matrix(matrix);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(r0*1.03)
    .outerRadius(r0*1.03 + 20);

var path = d3.svg.chord()
    .radius(r0);    

var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(chord.groups())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "group");

var paths = g.append("svg:path")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return fillcolor(rdr(d).gname); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fillcolor(rdr(d).gname); })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("class", "arcs");

var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .data(chord.chords())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "chord")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        //context = d3.select('canvas').node().getContext('2d');
        //context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        //context.fillStyle = 'gray';
        //context.lineWidth = '1px';

        currentTime = 500;
        current = currentTime * 0.15 * (0.5 + (Math.random()));
        currentPos = this.getPointAtLength(current);
        //context.beginPath();
        //context.fillStyle = "black";
        /*context.arc(
            Math.abs(currentPos.x),
            Math.abs(currentPos.y),
            2,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI
          );
          context.fill();*/
          currentpath = this;
          svg.insert("circle")
            .attr("cx",currentPos.x)
            .attr("cy",currentPos.y)
            .attr("r",2)
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
            .style("fill", this.style.fill)
           .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease(Math.sqrt)
            .attr("cx",function(){
              currentPos = currentpath.getPointAtLength(current+100);
              return currentPos.x;
            })
            .attr("cy",function(){
              currentPos = currentpath.getPointAtLength(current-100);
              return currentPos.y;
            })
            .remove();
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fillcolor(rdr(d.target).gname); })
    .attr("d", path);
}

function fillcolor(segmentvalue){
    if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment A")) {
        return '#ff3a21'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment C")) {
        return '#26bde2'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment D")) {
        return '#fcc30b'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment B")) {
        return '#dd1367'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment E")) {
        return '#a1e972'
    } else {
        return '#72e8a4'
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  #circle circle {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  path.chord {
    fill-opacity: .6;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: .25px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="d3/d3.js"></script>    
  <script src="d3/underscore.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/gistfile1.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chord.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my data file (out.csv):

```
Source,Destination,Count,
Segment A,Segment A,597.7731179,
Segment B,Segment A,428.4797097,
Segment C,Segment A,242.5536698,
Segment D,Segment A,39.18270781,
Segment F,Segment A,373.4118141,
Segment E,Segment A,342.1175938,
Segment B,Segment B,695.841404,
Segment C,Segment B,586.8204889,
Segment D,Segment B,519.0497198,
Segment F,Segment B,142.271554,
Segment E,Segment B,282.7048795,
Segment A,Segment B,552.8162888,
Segment C,Segment C,162.7852664,
Segment D,Segment C,150.6887517,
Segment F,Segment C,631.6468679,
Segment E,Segment C,611.0627425,
Segment A,Segment C,344.1286204,
Segment B,Segment C,395.710855,
Segment D,Segment D,141.5878005,
Segment F,Segment D,254.2566994,
Segment E,Segment D,483.4672747,
Segment A,Segment D,5.942896921,
Segment B,Segment D,185.6991357,
Segment C,Segment D,138.2424522,
```

I have implemented a close enough solution and hosted it at:
https://jsfiddle.net/Edwig_Noronha/fb9j5v4t/

Comment: have you ever looked at the path of a chord? what does the path describe? you need to calculate something else of the chord to let the particles move. Create some runnable snippet and not a bunch of code Copy-Paste.

Comment: @rioV8 It really is difficult to implement a runnable snippet when the hint is to calculate something else of the chord. I tried to figure out what that something else would be. I was able to implement the the following which is close enough but not exactly what I intended.

Comment: what I mean by "runnable snippet" is a version of **YOUR** current code that can run and show some output. Do not expect that viewers will construct a runnable version of your code segments to be able to see the code run or debug the code. You can hard code the input if it is not that big

Comment: @rioV8 I totally misunderstood that. I tried jsfiddle but could not figure out external dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//*******************************************************************
//  CREATE MATRIX AND MAP
//*******************************************************************
var matrix, mmap, rdr;
d3.csv('data/out.csv', function(error, data) {
    var mpr = chordMpr(data);

    mpr
        .addValuesToMap('Source')
        .setFilter(function(row, a, b) {
            return (row.Source === a.name && row.Destination === b.name)
        })
        .setAccessor(function(recs, a, b) {
            if (!recs[0]) return 0;
            return +recs[0].Count;
        });

    matrix = mpr.getMatrix();
    mmap = mpr.getMap();
    rdr = chordRdr(matrix, mmap);
    drawChords();
});


//*******************************************************************
//  DRAW THE CHORD DIAGRAM
//*******************************************************************
function drawChords() {
    var w = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
    h = 700,
    r1 = h / 2,
    r0 = r1 - 150;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("id", "circle")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

    var chord = d3.layout.chord()
        .padding(.15)
        .sortChords(d3.descending);

    chord.matrix(matrix);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(r0*1.03)
        .outerRadius(r0*1.03 + 20);

    var path = d3.svg.chord()
        .radius(r0);    

    var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
        .data(chord.groups())
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "group");

    var paths = g.append("svg:path")
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return fillcolor(rdr(d).gname); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return fillcolor(rdr(d).gname); })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("class", "arcs");

    var chordPaths = svg.selectAll("path.chord")
        .data(chord.chords(),function(d,i){return i;})
        .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "chord")
        .attr("id", function(d,i){return "chord"+i})
        .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
              this.classList.add("hovered");
              currentpath = this;
              startPoint = pathStartPoint(currentpath);

              function loop(thispath) {
                if (!thispath.classList.contains("hovered")) return;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    particle = svg.insert("circle")                
                        .attr("class",function(){return currentpath.getAttribute("id")+"-circle"})
                        .attr("r",2)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
                        .style("fill", currentpath.style.fill)
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + startPoint[0] + "," + startPoint[1] + ")")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(2000)
                        .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(currentpath))
                        .remove();
                    loop(thispath);
                }, 300);
              }

            loop(this);                                         
        })
        .on("mouseout",function(d,i){
            this.classList.remove("hovered");
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return fillcolor(rdr(d.target).gname); })
        .attr("d", path);
}

//Get path start point for placing marker
function pathStartPoint(path) {        
    var d = path.getAttribute("d");
    var dsplitted = d.split(" ");
    return dsplitted[1].split(",");
};

function translateAlong(path) {
    var l = path.getTotalLength();
    var t0 = 0;
    return function(i) {        
        return function(t) {                     
            var p0 = path.getPointAtLength(t0 * l);//previous point
            var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);////current point
            t0 = t;
            var centerX = p.x,
            centerY = p.y;
            return "translate(" + centerX + "," + centerY + ")"//rotate(" + angle + " 24" + " 12" +")";
        }
    }
}

function fillcolor(segmentvalue){
    if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment A")) {
        return '#ff3a21'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment C")) {
        return '#26bde2'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment D")) {
        return '#fcc30b'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment B")) {
        return '#dd1367'
    } else if (segmentvalue.includes("Segment E")) {
        return '#a1e972'
    } else {
        return '#72e8a4'
    }
}
```

The above changes in the chord.js file implement a close enough transition.
The working code is hosted at:
https://jsfiddle.net/Edwig_Noronha/fb9j5v4t/